# Why is bucket sort considered to be non-comparison sort?

Tags: algorithm

Why is Bucket sort considered to be a non-comparison based sorting algorithm (where no comparison of keys is performed for sorting the list) despite the fact that insertion sort, which is used to sort individual buckets is comparison based ?

Comment: *Comparison* sort is where we compare items with *one another*. In bucket sort we compare items with buckets' keys.

Comment: Because insertion-sorting the contents of each bucket is *not* a part of the bucket sort algorithm.  A bucket sort is done once the items are distributed into buckets.

Comment: in some cases (linear mapped ranges to buckets) the bucket sort can be done without any `if` statement (brunch-less) with 3 simple `O(n)` for loops (not nested) , computation of index (linear interpolation or direct) and copy of data between input/bucket/output arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is indeed a comparison sort, so you are right that *if* the buckets are sorted using insertion sort, *and* that is considered an integral part of bucket sort, *then* we should also call it a comparison sort.

But:

- The same happens in other algorithms as well. Quick sort and merge sort implementations will often switch to insertion sort when the partition becomes smaller than a certain threshold. To be entirely transparent, you should then say that these algorithms are a *mix* of two algorithms, and not *pure* quick sort, merge sort, and ... bucket sort.
- There is no rule that bucket sort *must* use another sorting algorithm to sort the buckets. Bucket sort can be implemented in a *pure* way, i.e. by sorting the buckets recursively using *bucket sort*, until all buckets have at the most 1 value.

Actually, the Wikipedia article on [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), addresses this consideration in the opening paragraph:

> ...Each bucket is then sorted individually, either using a different sorting algorithm, or by recursively applying the bucket sorting algorithm. It is a **distribution** sort [...]. Bucket sort can be implemented with comparisons and therefore can ***also*** be considered a **comparison** sort algorithm.